# When a 3-strand pretzel link is a knot?

Tags: knot-theory, knot-invariants

I'm working on an article about the 3-strand pretzel links and I came across this remark :

$P(p_1,p_2,p_3)$ is a knot if and only if none of two $p_i'$s are even.

So I thaught that the the number of even $p_i'$s is the number of components.

My question is how to prove the remark.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done in a case by case analysis on the diagrams.  If you only care about pretzel knots with 3 twisted regions, then you only have to have a few cases, based on whether there are an even or odd number of twists.

Also, you can further reduce your work by appealing to [the other question you asked](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1762899/the-isotopy-type-of-the-pretzel-three-strand-knot-pa-b-c), so you don't have to worry about where the even ones are in the diagram.

Good luck.